# How can we create 'special' files, like /dev/random, in linux?

Tags: linux, file, pipe, lazy-evaluation

In Linux file system, there are files such as /dev/zero and /dev/random which are not real files on hard disk.

Is there any way that we can create a similar file and tell it to get ouput from executing a program?

For example, can I create file, say /tmp/tarfile, such that any program reading it actually gets the output from the execution of a different program (/usr/bin/tar ...)?

Comment: What are you actually trying to *do*?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "lazy files", but there are certainly main "special files" that aren't "real" files on a hard disk.  "/dev/zero" and "/dev/random" are two examples.  So is just about anything under "/dev/*".  Or "/media/*".  You might be interested, too, in the Linux ["/proc" filesystem](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc).

Comment: PS: Linux also has multiple "compressed filesystems", including [cromfs](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/source/cromfs.html), [jffs2](http://sources.redhat.com/jffs2/) and [squashfs](http://squashfs.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: For example, I have a file compressed on hard disk but when program A opens it, a tar will work behind the file, and pipe the data to program A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to create such a file/program, but it would require creation of a special filesystem in order to insert hooks into the VFS so that accesses can be detected and handled properly.